# Declaring an empty type in di.xml

Tags: magento2, di, bug

What does [this line](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/CatalogSearch/etc/di.xml#L80) in `di.xml` do?

```
<type name="Magento\Framework\Search\EntityMetadata" />
```

It's just a `type` tag that closes immediately. There are no arguments passed to it, no plugins declared inside it...nothing. Just a type with a name.

I have a strong feeling that this does nothing and it's just a forgotten line, but I want to make sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line does nothing. My best guess is that it can be safely deleted.

Comment: will do. That's why I asked. I'm planning a PR to cleanup the di.xml files.

Comment: That's cool. I'm guessing it was used for something in the past but not needed anymore and is just a leftover of some refactoring. Maybe a search in the GIT history could show some light on this.

Comment: I did exactly that :). Looked through the history, but lost interest at one point.

Comment: Yes, history can be overwhelming at some point. Let's just remove it and see what breaks ;-)

Comment: Why doesn't it throw an error if it does nothing? If it does nothing that's a missing parameter at the very least.

Has anyone looked through the code that parses the xml here to see if there is a fallback to an abstract class if no class if provided?

Answer (score 0):

If I do a quick `grep` on a Magento 2.1.7 install, I see it being used several times being used in a Search Adapter:

```
$ grep -nR "Search\\\\EntityMetadata" --exclude-dir=cache --exclude-dir=tests --exclude-dir=Test
vendor/magento/module-catalog-search/etc/di.xml:63:    <type name="Magento\Framework\Search\EntityMetadata" />
vendor/magento/module-catalog-search/etc/di.xml:64:    <virtualType name="Magento\Framework\Search\ProductEntityMetadata" type="Magento\Framework\Search\EntityMetadata">
vendor/magento/framework/Search/Adapter/Mysql/Aggregation/Builder.php:14:use Magento\Framework\Search\EntityMetadata;
vendor/magento/framework/Search/Adapter/Mysql/DocumentFactory.php:28:     * @var \Magento\Framework\Search\EntityMetadata
vendor/magento/framework/Search/Adapter/Mysql/DocumentFactory.php:34:     * @param \Magento\Framework\Search\EntityMetadata $entityMetadata
vendor/magento/framework/Search/Adapter/Mysql/DocumentFactory.php:39:        \Magento\Framework\Search\EntityMetadata $entityMetadata
vendor/magento/framework/Search/Adapter/Mysql/Mapper.php:16:use Magento\Framework\Search\EntityMetadata;
```

Also I see it in Magento Enterprise in the Solr module:

```
vendor/magento/module-solr/SearchAdapter/DocumentFactory.php:28:     * @var \Magento\Framework\Search\EntityMetadata
vendor/magento/module-solr/SearchAdapter/DocumentFactory.php:34:     * @param \Magento\Framework\Search\EntityMetadata $entityMetadata
vendor/magento/module-solr/SearchAdapter/DocumentFactory.php:38:        \Magento\Framework\Search\EntityMetadata $entityMetadata
vendor/magento/module-solr/etc/di.xml:82:    <virtualType name="Magento\Solr\SearchAdapter\ProductEntityMetadata" type="Magento\Framework\Search\EntityMetadata">
```

Comment: but this has nothing to do with its presence in `di.xml`